# Эмуляция браузера на серверной стороне

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, php, сервер

Привет ребята!

Ситуация следующая: У меня есть веб-форма которую заполняет пользователь(к примеру логин и емейл). Эти данные отправляются на десяток других левых форм курлом. Беда в том, что другие формы периодически меняются(добавляются поля, в том числе скрытые, меняются пути к экшенам форм и т.д.). Причем логика работы этих форм описана на js.

Если такое происходит, то логику отправки данных на данную форму приходится полностью переписывать, т.е. включать сниффер и смотреть что изменилось. На исправление уходит как правило пара дней, поскольку приходится гадать на кофейной гуще. Форм много, поэтому все время уходит на поддержку всей этой беды.

Собственно, нужна эмуляция браузера на стороне сервера. Если меняются пути, скрытые поля и т.д., то это никак не должно повлиять на отправку данных.

Я даже не знаю по какому запросу гуглить и какие инструменты для этого подойдут... Может кто-то решал подобную задачу и может помочь?

Comment: думаю, что гуглить нужно по словам "рассылка спама УК".

Comment: Не)) Гуглить нужно по "Как заставить партнера написать api"...

Comment: Если это партнёр, то получать у него уведомления при изменении форм и пояснение логики их работы - не вопрос, который нужно обсуждать здесь...

Comment: Ага. Это типа проще...

Comment: Если они действительно партнёры и заинтересованы во взаимодействии с вами - то да, проще. В противном случае либо они не партнёры, либо у вас проблемы с организацией работы.

Comment: Надож было попасть на форум бизнесменов... Проблема организации работы - проблема моего начальства, а моя проблема ковырять всю эту пачку форм. По этому давайте не трогать моральную и организационную сторону вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Как то пару лет назад пытался сделать автоматизированую систему постинга обьявлений на доски. Тоже столкнулся с проблемой изменения количества полей в форме и имён. С статическими формами (которые сразу выдаются в браузер) вопрос решался просто. php код брал кусок html кода между тегами <form>(.*?)</form> и с помощью регулярок выискивал все поля. Сравнивал список найденых полей (тип,имя) со списком в БД. Если находились несоответствия отправка данных не производилась и мне приходило уведомление какие поля в форме на каком именно сайте изменились. Внесение изменений в код отправки занимало от нескольких минут до получаса максимум, так как знал что и где искать.
С формами в которые подгружались поля через js с динамическим добавлением новых полей было сложнее. Начал рыть в сторону node.js, так как этот фреймворк может выполнятся на стороне сервера. Но нагрузили по основной работе и проект забросил.

Answer (score 1):

[phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) - в настоящий момент использую его.

[selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) - не решился, в разы сложнее.

Comment: попробуйте CefSharp.OffScreen